# Is This an HTML Table Issue or a Modal Issue?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to incorporate a modal without bootstrap.  I've been at it for a couple of days and it's kinda working...but I can't seem to pass the ID properly to the delete.  If I click on the row...it's always passing the first ID of the table...I'm not sure now if it's an HTML table issue or a modal issue...

This works every time without fail for the right row...but here you'll see I'm doing an Onclick event...

```
<td class="hide">
  <button type="button" class="button114" onclick="return confirm('Click Ok to confirm delete, Cancel to ignore.');"><a href="{% url 'Main:notify_delete2' pk=notify.id %}">
        <div class="txtalgn114"><h2 class="txtalgn114a">Delete</h2></div></a></button></td>
```

If I try instead to a modal...It kinda works..it deletes a record...but now always the right row...

```
{% for notify in notify_list %}
  <tr style="vertical-align:top">
{% if user.userprofile.eDirector_queue_delete_confirm == "Yes" %}
<td class="hide">
  <div id="myModaldelete{{ notify.id }}" class="modaldelete">
    <div class="modal-content-delete">
      <span class="closedelete"></span>
      <img class="logo4" src="/static/images/threecircles.svg">
      <p>Delete Request?</p>
      <button type="button" class="button165" data-id="{{ notify.id }}">Yes</button>
      <button type="button" class="button160" id="noBtndelete">No</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="button114" data-id="{{ notify.id }}">
  <div class="txtalgn114"><h2 class="txtalgn114a">Delete</h2></div></button>
</td>
{% endif &}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to append the {{ notify.id }} to the ID and have tried passing in the data-id...but to no avail.  I'm starting to wonder if I need to approach this differently because it's an HTML table.

Comment: ids need to be unique. If you are including the `delete` id multiple times it won't work.

Comment: @Lee Taylor Fair point...but that's not really my issue.  Any thoughts on if it's an HTML table issue or a modal issue?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: @SteveSmith Hard to see without a running demo.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...After about a day or two of playing with this concept...I figured it out...I was missing a few things...Most importantly the back and forth with the Javascript and the ID value...I had to add the following Javascript logic...I moved the modal out of my loop and added a hidden input to get the ID value.  Thanks to all who helped me piece this one together.  It was complicated.  For me anyway.

```
   $('.button114').on('click', function (event) {
     modaldelete[0].style.display = "block";
     var id = $(this).data('id');
     document.getElementById("modal-input-value").value = id;
   });

   $('.button165').on('click', function (event) {
     // Get the hidden input element
     var hiddenInput = document.getElementById("modal-input-value");
     // Get the value of the hidden input
     var id = hiddenInput.value;
     document.location.href = "/url/" + id;
   });

  <div id="myModaldelete{{ notify.id }}" class="modaldelete">
    <div class="modal-content-delete">
      <span class="closedelete"></span>
      <img class="logo4" src="/static/images/threecircles.svg">
      <p>Delete Request?</p>
       <input type="hidden" id="modal-input-value">
      <button type="button" class="button165">Yes</button>
      <button type="button" class="button160" id="noBtndelete">No</button>
    </div>
  </div>

{% for notify in notify_list %}
  <tr style="vertical-align:top">
{% if user.userprofile.eDirector_queue_delete_confirm == "Yes" %}
<td class="hide">
  <button type="button" class="button114" data-id="{{ notify.id }}">
  <div class="txtalgn114"><h2 class="txtalgn114a">Delete</h2></div></button>
</td>
{% endif &}
{% endfor %}
```